# Encoding.GetEncoding("CP437") in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I am quite new in Silverlight 4 and Windows Phone 7 Development...

**My Requirement:**

```
  // It Gives error: 'CP437' is not a supported encoding name.   
  // (The same line works fine in C#.Net Console Application)  

  Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP437");  
  byte[] ByteArray = { 65, 127, 171, 174, 175, 171, 66, 0 };  
  char[] CharArray = enc.GetChars(ByteArray);
```

Any pointer on how to implement Encoding.GetEncoding("CP437") in Windows Phone 7 (C#.Net 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, code page 437 is the original IBM PC character set. This is not available on Windows Phone and as far as I know it never will be. As you can see here **A½«»B** most of your sample characters are available from unicode requiring only a translation table, but some like the DEL character and the IBM line drawing characters (not in your sample but present in code page 437) would require specialised character sets such as Terminal (which is an ancient bitmap font).

Perhaps if you gave more information about your purpose?

Comment: Peter thanks for reply - well i tried 1252 (Windows 1252) code page and that also not worked (Same result i.e "1252 is not a supported encoding name"). I do not know which code page is supported by Windows Phone 7. My requirement is: i have image raw data in bytes (i.e 0 to 255 value) and i want to convert these bytes into string. I have no problem in converting value between 0 to 127 but for 128 to 255 i am getting wrong or "?" values in string, i think i need to use proper encoding to convert all these characters and that is way i have tried Encoding.GetEncoding("CP437")/("1252")with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the custom Encoding class for Silverlight from Desktop .NET by writing your code or by using some code generator.

Check out this link for an detailed info and tool to do just that:

http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator/comment-page-1#comment-14440